# TableView binding and Object HAS-A relation

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following classes

```
Class Car{
  private StringProperty type;

  //+setters and getters
}

Class Person{
  private Car car;

  private StringProperty name;

  //+setters and getters 
}
```

And I have tableView `TableView<Person>`. In this tableView I have two columns - Person Name and Car Type.

This is how I build column for Person Name

```
TableColumn<Person,String> column=new TableColumn("Person Name");
column.setCellValueFactory(data->data.getValue().getName());
```

You can see, there can be two changes with Car in class Person. First of all a person can get another car, and secondly car can change its type.

How can I build column Car Type and bind to "these two changes"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [select* methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#selectString-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String...-) of the Bindings class are made for this:

```
carTypeColumn.setCellValueFactory(
    data -> Bindings.selectString(data.getValue(), "car", "type"));
```

Note that your getters and setters should follow JavaFX conventions, like all JavaFX classes do:

```
class Car {
    private final StringProperty type = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public StringProperty typeProperty() { return type; }
    public String getType() { return type.get(); }
    public void setType(String newType) { type.set(newType); }
}

class Person {
    private final ObjectProperty<Car> car = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();

    private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public ObjectProperty<Car> carProperty() { return car; }
    public Car getCar() { return car.get(); }
    public void setCar(Car newCar) { car.set(newCar); }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() { return name; }
    public String getName() { return name.get(); }
    public void setName(String newName) { name.set(newName); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've read the link you provided. However, from that link I don't see that it reacts also to events if car object will be replaced. Will it  react to "two changes"?

Comment: @Pavel You’re right, the documentation does not make it clear.  The answer is:  Yes, changes to any property in the chain will be recognized and will cause the entire binding to be re-evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should add `ObjectProperty<Car>` to your `Person` class to make car `Observable`. Then your binding will look like following:

```
carTypeName.setCellValueFactory(data ->
                Bindings.createStringBinding(
                        () -> data.getValue().getCar().get().getType().get(),
                                data.getValue().getCar(),
                                data.getValue().getCar().get().getType()));
```

This means that your cell will display new `Car.type` value each time either `Person.car` or `Person.car.type` is changed. (If `Person.car` can be `null` you might need to add additional `null` checks.)

Comment: Change the car first and the type of the new car later and you'll see this approach won't work, since you're still listening to the type of the **old** car.